# Backbone view not refreshing on JSON collection change

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

So I have a collection that is fueled by a JSON url. All I'm doing is rendering elements from the JSON URL into a template through my view. However, I can not get the view to refresh upon update to the JSON.

My view is currently this:

```
class wiki.Views.FileUpload extends Backbone.View
    el: '#category'

    initialize: ->
      @collection = new wiki.Collections.Files
      @collection.fetch().done(@render)
      @collection.on "change", @render, this
    render: =>
      @$el.html JST['templates/file_upload']
      @$ul = @$('#file_view')

      for page in @collection.models
        pageHtml = JST['templates/file_history']({
          page: page
        })
        @$ul.append(pageHtml)
      @show()
    show: =>
      @$el.show()
```

In my template I just render all the JSON using <%= @page.get('JsonElement') %> with some other HTML that isn't important. Anyway, basically my goal is for the view to refresh once the JSON changes from the collection. Any ideas?

Comment: does your template understands a full Backbone model instance you are throwing at it? Maybe you wanted `page: page.attributes`?

Comment: My page will fully render the first time through, correctly looping through each JSON object and displaying the correct HTML element. Basically, I know the "for page in @collection.models" is working correctly, but I added "@collection.on "change", @render, this" that line to try and get the view to refresh when the JSON changed, but it still won't refresh when the JSON changes.

Comment: How is your view supposed to know that the JSON changes? Is there a `fetch` call somewhere that refreshes the collection? BTW, you probably want to `JST['templates/file_upload']()`, passing a function to `.html` is a bad habit to pick up.

Comment: Duly noted. And that's what I'm missing. I understand fetch will get the data but I'm not sure if I need to program it so it will check, or if there's some way for it to automatically trigger if the JSON changes.